# Recover data from RAID 5 with VMFS data store

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, raid5, data-recovery

I own an HP Proliant Gen-6 ML350 server which is not turning on again after a power outage. According to my research it is most likely due to a failue of the power supply backplane or the power supply, alternatively the mainboard, a CPU or a combination thereof. I'm going to try fixing it but don't hold up great hopes.

I have five 300GB SAS drives in RAID 5 configuration and since my server won't boot up I would like to recover data on that RAID. This data has been backed up weeks ago but I would really like to access the recent data.

However, I do not have another HP system to rebuild the RAID on. I do however have a Windows workstation with an LSI RAID card and I am wondering whether I could plug the five drives into that and then use software such as Stellar Data Recovery to recover it?

An important note is that the server is a VMware ESXi server and the data I wish to recover is from the VMs that were stored within the VMFS datastore.

Do I have any chance at recovering this?

Comment: If you dont have spare equipment, or a support contract with HP, I'd recommend buying a 2nd hand HP Proliant Gen-6 ML350 for spares/repair and recover to there, if your data is very important to you.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to move the RAID from one server to another only if the RAID controllers are the same or from the same vendor. Metadata stored on the drives, but the configuration is located in the RAID controller itself. It is better to restore the server itself and then move all data from the old server.

Comment: I think that it is technically possible to recover data from 'foreign' RAID sets if you can connect the drives via any HBA. Clever people will know the settings used by the HP RAID card and there is commercial software to assist with this.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to hear to help me decide. I just got lucky and bought an identical server as a parts donor, hopefully I can get it fixed and restore the data this way.